# New users should be able to upload images

Tags: feature-request

This is hard to believe, I want to ask for some help, but doing it just by text is really annoying. I have to wait for some reputation to do that, how do you want me to get fast help then?

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user), anyone with at least 10 reputation should be able to post images. As explained there, this is largely to guard against spam from new users who may be just bots in disguise.

Comment: Why can't we allow new users to post images provided that they complete a somewhat rigorous [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) (a requirement which would be lifted or decreased at 10 rep)?

Answer (score 8):

You can always post a link to the image hosted on an online image-sharing site like [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/), and one of us with higher reputation will gladly edit it in properly for you until you earn the privilege to do so on your own.